# How can I highlight line number with VSCode extension API?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to show a warning message in the vscode editor with a highlighted line. VSCode has API for showing warning message but it suggests to use custom theme for highlighting syntax. Is there any way for highlighting lines in the editor with a Simple API call? Like - vscode.DocumentHighlight - with this one ?

Comment: define a custom color, and mark a range with this color

Comment: I already have generated an extension by using Yeoman ! Can I define color in the existing extension project or do I need to  generate a new theme extension separately?

Comment: you have a `colors` `contribution` point

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little , what API should I call after defining a color in the contribution point? I really appreciate your help sir !

Comment: have you looked at the methods of the TextEditor?